# How to open header file by terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I want to open header file in /usr/local/include.
How to open it by terminal?

Comment: Open with what? Text editor? usually you type `name-of-your-editor /usr/local/include/name-of your.h`. For example `vim /usr/local/include/foobar.h`. Maybe I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need permissions to open the file (read, and write if you want to edit). Then I would use `vi`/`vim`, or a more "user friendly" `nano`, followed by the name of your header file, to read its contents, assuming you are already inside `/usr/local/include`.